# How to place variable in Powershell try/catch block

Tags: string, powershell

I have a variable in my script for my path:

```
$path = "C:\project\"
```

Then in a function I have:

```
function DoWork {
    try 
    {
        C:\project\myapp.exe /silent
    }
    catch 
    {

    }
}
```

I want to replace the string literal in the try block with the variable. I have tried putting ${path} there, and ($path + "myapp.exe /silent") along with other combinations but I seem to get errors still.

What is the correct way to replace the literal path with the path variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a dynamic list of arguments to an external function call (based on your comments), use splatting:

```
$Params = @('/silent','/quiet')
$exe = "$Path\myapp.exe"
& $exe @Params
```

Answer (score 5):

Construct your path as a string, then supply the string as an argument to the call operator (`&`):

```
try 
{
    $appPath = Join-Path $path myapp.exe
    & $appPath
}
catch 
{

}
```

Subsequent string arguments to `&` will be treated as arguments to the command represented by the first argument:

```
& $appPath '/silent'
```

Comment: I meant to write there was an additional argument after the .exe like '/silent'. How would I handle that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
    function DoWork {
    $path = "C:\project\"
    try 
    {
        "$path\myapp.exe"
    }
    catch 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't $path need to be enclosed in curly brackets like "${path}", otherwise how will Powershell know when the end of the variable name occurs?

Comment: In C# you have to use variables like that. In Powershell anything with a $ in front is assumed to be a variable within a string.  This works just fine for combining string variables into a larger string.

Comment: @WilliamRoss I recommend using the ISE while writing scripts and seeing how the highlighting works.  It will interpret the variable until it reaches a special character.  If you want to sub text in the middle of a string, then go ahead and use the `${}` syntax

Comment: The slash is recognized as a boundary even without qualifying the variable name with curly brackets (as is `-` and `$`)